# What is a FHS compliant installation dir for vendor-provided binaries?

Tags: debian, fhs

A software vendor has to create a [Linux filesystem hierarchy standard (FHS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) compliant Debian package.
What installation dir has to be used for binaries?

Software placed in `/bin` or `/usr/bin` may be overwritten by system upgrades. Is it okay to install binaries in that directories? Or are this directories reserved for the base system distributor?

`/usr/local/bin` is for software installed by the system administrator.
Everything under `/usr/local` must not be modified by system upgrades.
A vendor-provided Debian package may become part of the system upgrade procedure if it is downloaded from a package repository and this repository is registered with `apt-add-repository`. Therefore, I guess: No?

`/opt/<vendor>/bin` seems to be okay. But doesn't this directory have to be registered somewhere to avoid conflicts with other vendors? And how to integrate this directory in a FHS compliant way to make `$PATH` work?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consult [how Debian outlines /opt](https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard):

> /opt/ Add-on application software packages  Pre-compiled, non ".deb"
>   binary distribution (tar'ed..) goes here.
>
> /opt/bin/ : Same as for top-level hierarchy
>
> /opt/include/ : Same as
>   for top-level hierarchy
>
> /opt/lib/ : Same as for top-level hierarchy
>
> /opt/sbin/ : Same as for top-level hierarchy
>
> /opt/share/ : Same as for
>   top-level hierarchy

In practice, I've seen applications that do install `.deb` packages there as well. Ideally, `/bin` and `/usr/bin` should be reserved, and especially `/bin` because it is defined as

> Essential command executable (binaries) for all users (e.g., cat, ls, cp) 
>   (especially files required to boot or rescue the system)

In practice, it's common to see debian packages from 3rd parties installing to  `/usr/bin` on Debian-based systems, probably because `/usr/bin` is often part of the `PATH` variable,so it can be easily launched via command-line. You've mentioned:"Software placed in /bin or /usr/bin may be overwritten by system upgrades". Upgrades target removal of specific files in `/usr/bin`, so yes it may be overwritten but not unless some `.deb` package specified removal of yours explicitly (as for example I've encountered with an applet package that removed older version of a dock that I use ). Upgrades can be dangerous if your software depends on specific binary **version** to be present in `/usr/bin`.

Another common thing I've seen is symlinking: entry in `/usr/bin` is a symlink to another location. This might be a viable option for integrating the binary into `$PATH` as you mentioned in the question. Additionally, this goes along with what Debian's [packaging manual regarding FHS](http://4.4.%20/usr/bin%20:%20Most%20user%20commands%20%204.4.1.%20Purpose%20%20%20%20%20This%20is%20the%20primary%20directory%20of%20executable%20commands%20on%20the%20%20%20%20system.) states:

> 4.4. /usr/bin : Most user commands
>
> 4.4.1. Purpose
>
> This is the primary directory of executable commands on the
>   system.
>
> 4.4.2. Requirements
>
> There must be no subdirectories in /usr/bin.

So, if you have application that expects subdirectories ( such as Python module with submodule directories ), best practice is to probably place the application elsewhere ([in case of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9388115/3701431), that's `/usr/lib/python*/dist-packages` directory) along with subdirectories, and make a symlink to `/usr/bin/my_binary`

Another `$PATH` integration I've seen being done by some vendors is to edit user's `$PATH` variable and append that to `~/.bashrc`. (Yes, this is a poor practice, and I don't encourage it - merely stating the fact that's what I've seen being done).

"But doesn't this directory have to be registered somewhere to avoid conflicts with other vendors?" The mentioned Debian documentation doesn't say anything about registering the directory, so the answer is *it doesn't have to*, but if you do want to avoid a conflict, you could follow the schema `/opt/vendor/package-v-1.2/bin` - that is specify package and release version, maybe a year as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the software to `/usr/local` directory hierarchy, just like if it was `/usr`. “Installed by system administrator” means simply that the administrator (or for single-user desktop systems, the user) decided to not use the system's package management and install that directly. When the file is looked up (this applies to `$PATH` lookup and also to library lookup etc.), `/usr/local` is preferred over `/usr`.

For example of the use, see defaults of some build systems like GNU Autotools, CMake or Meson. All of these default to installing to `/usr/local`. But the operating system distributor should instead configure them to use `/usr`. The administrator does not have to modify anything.

Usually, installing to `/usr/local` means that the application was built from source code and installing to `/opt` means that the application is binary compiled on computer of someone else.

There can be also hidden directory `.local` in each user's home that can contain its own set of programs. It is used just like `/usr/local` – there can be `~/.local/bin`, `~/.local/share` etc.

One of multiply common practices of installing application from archives is dumping the archive contents to an appropriate `/opt` subdirectory (e.g. `/opt/graalvm-ce-java11-22.0.0.2`) and making symlinks to the files here from `/usr/local/bin` and other directories under `/usr/local` to the application files. Example follows.

```
/usr/local/bin/java -> /opt/graalvm/bin/java
```

It is also quite common to make switching multiple versions of the application installed to `/opt` easier by adding version information to its directory name (e.g. `/opt/graalvm-ce-java11-22.0.0.2`) and making symlink (e.g. `/opt/grallvm`) to that directory.

Comment: Note that the OP is specifically asking about creating a *package*, so they do want the administrator to use the system’s package management.